# Fetching rollouts failed Google Endpoints on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, grpc, google-kubernetes-engine

This is the log I got from the pod on GKE.

> esp   Aug 29, 2018, 2:58:59 PM    ERROR:Fetching rollouts failed (status code 403, reason Forbidden, url https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog/rollouts?filter=status=SUCCESS)
>
> esp   Aug 29, 2018, 2:58:57 PM    INFO:Fetching the service config ID from the rollouts service
>
> esp   Aug 29, 2018, 2:58:57 PM    INFO:Fetching an access token from the metadata service

I can see my endpoint service using:

```
gcloud endpoints configs list --service=myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog
```

> 2018-08-29r3  myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog
>
> 2018-08-29r2  myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog
>
> 2018-08-29r1  myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog
>
> 2018-08-29r0  myapp.endpoints.xxxxx.cloud.goog

I also have service permission enabled on my GKE cluster.

```
Service Control  Enabled
Service Management  Read Write
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out I need [create credentials for your service](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes#create_credentials), even I'm on google kubernetes engine.

Comment: It is also worth noting, that the primary reason why this fails is a missing oauth scope in the default cluster service account. They are only assigned on cluster creation! Also if you create your cluster via terraform, you must explicitly assign the oauth scopes, otherwise it won't work. I recommend using a dedicated serviceAccount here, it gives more flexibility and ensures you have the right permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the answer - I was legit going insane

Answer (score 0):

For me I forgot to deploy swagger file to endpoints. After deploying endpoints it is fixed.